# how to calculate width of component in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to calculate the width of child component .is it possible to calculate width of children's ? here is my code
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-hermann-yt7es?file=/src/App.js

```
<Tabs>
      {data.map((i) => (
        <li>{i}</li>
      ))}
    </Tabs>
```

TABS.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Tabs = ({ children }) => {
  const tabsRef = useRef(null);

  const setTabsDimensions = () => {
    if (!tabsRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    // initial wrapper width calculation
    const blockWidth = tabsRef.current.offsetWidth;
    // const showMoreWidth = moreItemRef.current.offsetWidth;

    // calculate width and offset for each tab
    let tabsTotalWidth = 0;
    const tabDimensions = {};

    children.forEach((tab, index) => {
      if (tab) {
        console.log(tab);
        
        // const width = !isMobile ? 200 : 110;

        // tabDimensions[index] = {
        //   width,
        //   offset: tabsTotalWidth
        // };
        // tabsTotalWidth += width;
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTabsDimensions();
  });
  return (
    <ul ref={tabsRef} className="rc64nav">
      {children}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Tabs;
```

I know using **ref** we can access the dom property but how to apply ref in children element element.
**here i am trying to calculate all item width**

```
   children.forEach((tab, index) => {
              if (tab) {
                console.log(tab);
```

Comment: If you have a ref, than getting the width [is trivial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) but the real question is "why?" because you kind of shouldn't need to know the width of _any_ element, you should just have layout and CSS that makes things work at however many breakpoints you're written CSS for? (With base values encoded in your CSS either as native CSS variables, or through some preprocessor like sass, stylus, etc. but native CSS vars almost always win in terms of functionality)

Answer (score 0):

Just answer your question how to get child's ref.

```
  const Parent = () => {
    const childRef = useRef()

    // An example of use the childRef
    const onClick = () => {
     if (!childRef.current) return
      
     console.log(childRef.current.offsetWidth)
    }


    return <Child childRef={childRef} />
  }

  const Child = ({ childRef }) => {
   return <div ref={childRef}>Hello Child</div>
  }
```

NOTE: the way I pass ref here is exactly the same way you pass parent method to child. And also ref supports two formats, i'm using the simple one, but you can also use `() => {}` format. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: but i have multiple child

Comment: i have multiple `li's`

Comment: two approaches, A) ref.current.children, you can still do what a normal DOM can do. B) ref.current can be  an array,  `<div ref={r => {refArray.push(r) }} />`